# Identified the correct element and it's parent yet I am unable to delete it

Tags: javascript

- Set up ES6 classes correctly. Identified the correct element to be removed but nothing happens when remove button is clicked.
- Used console.log to make sure the event was registered and trigger. It shows up but I cannot remove an element from the DOM.
- Other methods in the class works perfectly, only the deleteBook() method inside the class UI gives me trouble. The debugger console does not show me any fault.

```js
class UI {
  static displayBooks() {
    const storedBooks = [{
        title: 'Book One',
        author: 'John Doe',
        isbn: '3434434'
      },
      {
        title: 'Book Two',
        author: 'Jane Doe',
        isbn: '4554576'
      },


    ];
    const books = storedBooks;
    books.forEach((book) => UI.addBookToList(book));
  }
  // Now we grab HTML section to display the book list we submit - create HTML - append / render it to the DOM 
  static addBookToList(book) {
    const list = document.querySelector('#book-list'); // This section displays the book's list we submitted.
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.innerHTML = `
              <td>${book.title}</td>
              <td>${book.author}</td>
              <td>${book.isbn}</td>
              <td><a href ="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-smdelete">X</a></td>
              `;
    list.appendChild(row);

  }
  // NOTE: we target the parentElement of parentElement so the entire row can be removed
  // Otherwise only click button will be removed when we click on it.
  static deleteBook(el) {
    if (el.classList.contains('delete')) {
      el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }

  // This class is utilized later on for us to clear out the input fields
  static clearField() {
    document.querySelector('#title').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#author').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#isbn').value = '';
  }
}
// EVENT: ADD A BOOK
document.querySelector('#book-form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

  // Fist we need to prevent actual submit
  e.preventDefault();

  // Now we will grab the form values
  const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
  const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
  const isbn = document.querySelector('#isbn').value;

  // Instantiate book Class
  const book = new Book(title, author, isbn);

  // Now books get added each time we click the submit button by accessing UI.addBookToList();
  UI.addBookToList(book);

  // Once submited we want all existing texts in the input field to disappear
  UI.clearField();
});

// EVENT: We would like to remove a book if we don't want it anymore
document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Remove book from UI
  UI.deleteBook(e.target);
})

// EVENT: Display list of BOOKS to the DOM... 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayBooks);
```

```html
<form id="book-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" id="author" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="isbn">ISBN#</label>
    <input type="text" id="isbn" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <input type="submit" value=" Add Book" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">

  <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
    <thead>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>ISBN#</th>
      <th></th>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="book-list"></tbody>
  </table>


</form>
```

Comment: where is that remove() function coming from in `el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();` unless there is a remove() function I don't see try `el.parentElement.parentElement.removeChild`

Comment: Is the question why clicking an `X` doesn't delete that line? If so, the answer is that you're looking for the class `delete` on the `X` element, and it doesn't have that class.

Comment: @MichaelCacciano - It's [part of the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), has been for a few years now.

Comment: well I'll be damned how did I miss that. sorry about that

Comment: @MichaelCacciano - The DOM was essentially unchanged for so long, we all get caught by surprise by the fact that...it's actually getting improvements now. :-) (Another recent handy one is `closest`, which is pretty much just like jQuery's.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I DID have the delete class but had it as "btn-smdelete" hence why the if(el.classList.contains('delete')) did not pick it up. but console.log did 

Added a space to it "btn-sm delete" and it works. 
Thank you so much for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully Working Solution With Mistakes highlighted

```
   <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" id ="title" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="author">Author</label>
                        <input type="text" id ="author" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="isbn">ISBN#</label>
                        <input type="text" id ="isbn" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" id="addBook" value=" Add Book" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">

                <table class="table table-striped mt-5">
                   <thead>
                     <th>Title</th>
                     <th>Author</th>
                     <th>ISBN#</th>
                     <th></th>
                   </thead> 

                   <tbody id="book-list"></tbody>
                </table>


        </form>

JAVASCRIPT HERE
<script>
//You had no script tag
class Book {//you had no book class
    constructor(title, author,isbn) {
        this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}

class UI {
    static displayBooks () {
        const storedBooks = [
            {
                title: 'Book One',
                author: 'John Doe',
                isbn: '3434434'
            },
            {
                title: 'Book Two',
                author: 'Jane Doe',
                isbn: '4554576'
            },


        ];
        const books = storedBooks;
        books.forEach((book) =>  UI.addBookToList(book));
}



    // Now we grab HTML section to display the book list we submit - create HTML - append / render it to the DOM 
    static addBookToList(book) {
        const list = document.querySelector('#book-list'); // This section displays the book's list we submitted.
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
              row.innerHTML = `
              <td>${book.title}</td>
              <td>${book.author}</td>
              <td>${book.isbn}</td>
              <td><a href ="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-smdelete">X</a></td>
              `;  
    list.appendChild(row);    

    }
    // NOTE: we target the parentElement of parentElement so the entire row can be removed
    // Otherwise only click button will be removed when we click on it.
    static deleteBook(el) {
        debugger;//fix here
        if(el.classList.contains("btn-smdelete")) {
          el.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
      }

    // This class is utilized later on for us to clear out the input fields
    static clearField() {
        document.querySelector('#title').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#author').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#isbn').value = '';
    }
}
// EVENT: ADD A BOOK
document.getElementById('addBook').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    // Fist we need to prevent actualy submit
    e.preventDefault();

    // Now we will grab the form values
    const title = document.querySelector('#title').value;
    const author = document.querySelector('#author').value;
    const isbn = document.querySelector('#isbn').value;

    // Instatiate book Class
    const book = new Book(title, author, isbn);

    // Now books get added each time we click the submit button by accessing UI.addBookToList();
    UI.addBookToList(book);

    // Once submited we want all existing texts in the input field to disappear
    UI.clearField();
});

// EVENT: We would like to remove a book if we don't want it anymore
document.querySelector('#book-list').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // Remove book from UI
    UI.deleteBook(e.target);
    })

// EVENT: Display list of BOOKS to the DOM... 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayBooks);

</script>
```